# Passing EventHandler as argument from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling

I have existing VB GUI code and I am trying to interface with some C# code but can't work out how to pass the EventHandler to VB.NET.

The C# signature is:

```
public void SendLatestImages(Guid PatientID, Guid ToPracticeID, EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs> progressChangedHandler)
    {
        ...
    }
```

In VB when I try to consume this, I have

```
sendImages.SendLatestImages(arg.PatientID, arg.ToPracticeID, ProgressStream_ProgressChanged)
```

So far so good. But in the ProgressStream_ProgressChanged function I only get:

```
Private Function ProgressStream_ProgressChanged() As EventHandler(Of SLSyncClient.ProgressChangedEventArgs)

End Function
```

... There is no access to the actual ProgressChangedEventArgs that I am after. In C#, the signature on this last function is

```
private void ProgressStream_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
```

... which gives me the args as e.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `ProgressStream_ProgressChanged` is a method that *returns* an event handler, not a method that is the event handler itself. What your code does is that it *invokes* `ProgressStream_ProgressChanged` (you don't need parentheses for that in VB) and passes its result to `SendLatestImages`.

What you want to do is to make `ProgressStream_ProgressChanged` into a `Sub` that *matches* the `EventHandler` delegate (and not a `Function` that returns it):

```
Private Sub ProgressStream_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, args As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
End Sub
```

Then you can use `AddressOf` to create a delegate out of it (in C# you don't need any operator for that, in VB you do):

```
sendImages.SendLatestImages(arg.PatientID, arg.ToPracticeID, AddressOf ProgressStream_ProgressChanged)
```

Comment: Perfect. I was missing the AddressOf. (I had tried the sub with the correct signature). Thank you @svick